# Looping throught database

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

So, normally I loop through a database like this;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 // echoes here
}
```

And this works fine. But what if I want to do something ling this?

```
<h1><?= $row["category_name"]; ?></h1>
<p><?= $row["description"]; </p>

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 // echoes here
}
```

This of course doesn't work because the `mysql_fetch_array` is below the first `$row`. But something like this doesn't work.. (infinite loop).

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

<h1><?= $row["category_name"]; ?></h1>
<p><?= $row["description"]; </p>

while($row) {
 // echoes here
}
```

What is the best way to solve this? Another database query for the first echoes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of: stop using `mysql`, its deprecated. Start looking at `mysqli` or `pdo`

Now I guess that all your rows contain the same data for `category_name` and thats why you want to print it first. The easiest way to do that, is to keep track if you are in the first iteration of the while loop.

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $counter++;
   if ($counter==1) {
    echo '<h1>'.$row['category_name'].'</h1><p>'.$row['description'].'</p>';

     //now if your first row only contains this information and doesnt have any regular data, uncomment the continue line.
     //continue;
   } 

   //echoes the regular rows.

}
?>
```

This could also be extended to check if the category name actually changed. So you could print the header when it changed.

```
<?php
$header = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if ($header!=$row['category_name']) {
    echo '<h1>'.$row['category_name'].'</h1><p>'.$row['description'].'</p>';
    $header = $row['category_name'];
   } 

   //echoes the regular rows.
}
?>
```

Now everytime the category name changes, the header will be printed with the description. Keep in mind that your query does need to have an `ORDER BY` on category_name for this to work properly, else you could end up with duplicate headers.

Comment: I like this solution! Quick and simple, just what I wanted. I'll also look into mysqli. I've heard about it, but didn't know mysql was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch only the first row, move the pointer to the second row and then loop over the result.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

<h1><?= $row["category_name"]; ?></h1>
<p><?= $row["description"]; </p>

mysql_data_seek($result,1);

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   // echoes here
}
```